# Generate random integer between 100 and 2000 in steps of 100 Java

Tags: java, math, integer

Im currently trying to get a random integer between 100 and 2000 in steps of 100 like 300, 800, 1400 etc.

Thats what I found to get a random number between a range, but how do I manage to get a random number in steps of 100?

```
Random random = new Random();
int start = 100;
int end = 2000;
int result = random.nextInt(start - end) + start;
```

Comment: Why not get a random number between 1 and 20 and multiply the result by 100.

Comment: or do you need them in increasing order

Comment: Define what that means. Show a few examples of possible output from your algorithm.

Comment: Possible outputs from my algorithm: `1139 121 432 923 254 862 1385` and I want those random numbers to be like this for example: `1100  100 400 900 200 800 1300`. They dont need to be increased. just random numbers.

Comment: `int result = ((random.nextInt(end - start) + start) / 100) * 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is whether you want 2000 included or not. And whether the step size reaches 2000 exactly. The calculation just needs to include the step size:

```
Random random = new Random();
final int start = 100;
final int end = 2000;
final int step = 100;
int result = start + step * random.nextInt((end - start)/step); // end excl.
int result = start + step * random.nextInt((end - start)/step + 1); // end incl.
```

[As already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524450/generate-random-integer-between-100-and-2000-in-steps-of-100-java#comment131553453_74524450), it is probably more clear to base all on a random number between 1 and 20, and scale that up.

```
int result = (1 + random.nextInt(20)) * 100; // 100 upto 2000 by 100.
```